# Read file with Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

Is it possible with Rhino Server-side Javascript to locate and read the contents of an arbitrary local file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure is.

from interpreter:

```
js> readFile('./tmp.txt');
```

or in code:

```
var filesz = readFile('./tmp.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to read a binary file using `charCodeAt` on the results from `readFile` don't return the expected values for bytes above `0x7F`. If you want to read a binary file, it works better to do something like:

```
var readBinaryFile=function(path){
    var file=java.io.RandomAccessFile(path,'r');
    var bytes=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, file.length());
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Which will give you a byte array.

**Warning:** When you read the bytes from that array it will treat them as signed i.e. `0xFF` is interpreted as `-1`. (If you know an easy way to fix this please comment.)